# Application crashes all the time - Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, unicorn

I've got a problem with Heroku. Everything was okay for some time, but later application started to crash all the time. There were no changes that could cause such behavior. Here is what heroku logs say:

```
2013-12-24T13:02:33.056291+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-12-24T13:02:39.813510+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec unicorn -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
2013-12-24T13:02:41.529872+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn.rb:5:in `require': cannot load such     file -- rack (LoadError)
2013-12-24T13:02:41.529872+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2013-12-24T13:02:41.529872+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/launcher.rb:9:in `require'
2013-12-24T13:02:41.529872+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/bin/unicorn:3:in `require'
2013-12-24T13:02:41.529872+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/launcher.rb:9:in `<top (    required)>'
2013-12-24T13:02:41.529872+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/bin/unicorn:3:in `<top (required)>'
2013-12-24T13:02:41.529872+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
2013-12-24T13:02:41.529872+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
2013-12-24T13:02:42.643135+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-12-24T13:02:42.658659+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

If I try to make heroku run rake db:migrate, I'm getting this:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:23:in `load': cannot load such file --      /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/specifications/bin/rake (LoadError)
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

After heroku run rails c, I'm getting this:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails.rb:14:in `require': cannot load such file -- action_dispatch/railtie (LoadError)
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
from /app/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Would be great if anyone can help with this. Thanks!

UPD:
Here is my config/unicorn.rb:

```
timeout 30
preload_app true
worker_processes Integer(ENV['UNICORN_WORKERS'] || 3)
listen ENV['PORT'], :backlog => Integer(ENV['UNICORN_BACKLOG'] || 16)

before_fork do |server, worker|
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
    Rails.logger.info('Disconnected from ActiveRecord')
  end

  sleep 1
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
    Rails.logger.info('Connected to ActiveRecord')
  end
end
```

and here is my Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -c ./config/unicorn.rb
```

Comment: Hey there, you've got a config/unicorn.rb file right? All that's set up?

Comment: and if you run *webrick* all is ok?

Comment: yes, with webrick everything is okay

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your `Procfile` is configured correctly.  Per [the Heroku Unicorn docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn), I think you need to define the port in your `Procfile` as well.

Here's my `unicorn.rb` file that runs fine on Unicorn, and the corresponding `Procfile`:

```
# config/unicorn.rb

worker_processes Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 3)
timeout Integer(ENV['WEB_TIMEOUT'] || 15)
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|

  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end  

after_fork do |server, worker|

  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to sent QUIT'
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Procfile

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
```

Comment: Thanks for advise. I've tried it and it didn't work as well. I've tried to deploy application to another heroku (with the same config) and everything works. Strange...